# inserting array index at second array last

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have situation . I want to insert one array element to another array element but could not find the exact method.

**This is my function**

```
public function get_applicants($sort_array = array('apply_id DESC'))
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->tableac . " ORDER BY " . implode(',', $sort_array);
    //$sql = 'SELECT c. * , p. * FROM wp_apply c, wp_apply_files p WHERE c.apply_id = p.apply_id';
    $educations = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $getid=array();
    foreach($educations as $education){
        //print_r($education);
        $sqlfile = 'SELECT * FROM wp_apply_files WHERE apply_id = '.$education->apply_id;
        $getalls = $wpdb->get_results($sqlfile);
        $allvalues="";
            foreach($getalls as $getall){
                $allvalues= $getall->uploaded_file.", ";
                $getid[]=$getall->uploaded_file;
            }
           $allvaluesnew=rtrim($allvalues,", "); 
         // echo "<br>";
         // Here I want to insert getid into educations array
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($educations);
    die();
    //return array($educations,$getid);
}
```

print_r result show this.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [apply_id] => 44
        [choose_position] => HR Manager
        [title] => testr
        [first_name] => waqas
        [last_name] => aamer
        [current_job] => developer
```

print_r get id show like this.

```
Array
(
[0] => a75d138911c55df639fdd09fade511151-23.pdf
[1] => newone3.pdf
[2] => a75d138911c55df639fdd09fade511151-22.pdf
[3] => newone2.pdf
[4] => a75d138911c55df639fdd09fade511151 (2).pdf
[5] => newone.pdf
)
```

I want to insert these these elements iteration wise. When in the educations first iteration comes than it should insert all the elements at one index of second array separated by comma.

Comment: Can you give me example array do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then following might help.
It will insert comma separated values from `$getid` into new key called "getid" in `$educations` array.

```
public function get_applicants($sort_array = array('apply_id DESC'))
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->tableac . " ORDER BY " . implode(',', $sort_array);
    //$sql = 'SELECT c. * , p. * FROM wp_apply c, wp_apply_files p WHERE c.apply_id = p.apply_id';
    $educations = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $getid=array();
    foreach($educations as $key => $education){
        //print_r($education);
        $sqlfile = 'SELECT * FROM wp_apply_files WHERE apply_id = '.$education->apply_id;
        $getalls = $wpdb->get_results($sqlfile);
            foreach($getalls as $getall){
                $getid[]=$getall->uploaded_file;
            }
         // echo "<br>";
         // Here I want to insert getid into educations array
         $educations[$key]["getid"] = implode(",", $getid);
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($educations);
    die();
    //return array($educations,$getid);
}
```

Hope this helps and this is what you want